# JOOQ and PostgreSQL types in a DSL select

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I have a problem with jOOQ 3.8.
So, I have a table in PostgreSQL 9.5, something like.

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table(
  id bigserial,
  types my_type[]
)
```

where the my_type is a type like

```sql
CREATE TYPE my_type AS(
  id smallint,
  something text
)
```

Now, in jOOQ 3.8 I want to do something like

```java
dsl.selectDistinct(MY_TABLE.ID)
   .from(MY_TABLE)
   .join(TYPE_TABLE).on(TYPE_TABLE.ID.equal(DSL.any(
       MY_TABLE.TYPES.ID
   ))
   .fetch(MY_TABLE.ID);
```

Clearly the step in which I do `MY_TABLE.TYPES.ID` is wrong. I was thinking about using `DSL.select(MY_TYPE.ID)...` but clearly the my_type is a type, not a table.

How can I access type properties using jOOQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to solve this with PostgreSQL

I don't think there's an easy way to transform your `my_type[]` into an `integer[]` type in PostgreSQL, extracting `my_type.id` for each value, for it to be usable with the `any()` operator.

But you can work around this limitation by using `UNNEST()`, something like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT my_table.id
FROM my_table
CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(my_table.types)
```

The above will yield something like

```
id   types                      id   something
----------------------------------------------
1    {"(1,a)","(2,b)"}          1    a
1    {"(1,a)","(2,b)"}          2    b
2    {"(1,a)","(2,b)","(3,c)"}  1    a
2    {"(1,a)","(2,b)"}          2    b
2    {"(1,a)","(2,b)"}          3    c
```

Now this, you can join again to `TYPE_TABLE`, such as:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT my_table.id
FROM my_table
CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(my_table.types) types
INNER JOIN type_table ON type_table.id = types.id
```

Or, probably better performing:

```sql
SELECT my_table.id
FROM my_table
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM type_table
  JOIN unnest(my_table.types) AS types ON type_table.id = types.id
)
```

#### How to solve this with jOOQ

jOOQ's unnest support is currently (as of version 3.8) rather simple, i.e. you don't get all the type information in the resulting table, which is why you need to do some plain SQL mingling. But it's certainly doable! Here's how:

```java
create().select(MY_TABLE.ID)
        .from(MY_TABLE)
        .whereExists(
            selectOne()
            .from(unnest(MY_TABLE.TYPES).as("types", 
                 MY_TYPE.ID.getName(), 
                 MY_TYPE.SOMETHING.getName()
             ))
            .join(TYPE_TABLE)
            .on(TYPE_TABLE.ID.eq(field(name("types", MY_TYPE.ID.getName()), 
                                     MY_TYPE.ID.getDataType())))
        )
        .fetch(MY_TABLE.ID);
```